# Unable to link to org in Force.com IDE

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide

Using Eclipse Kepler, I've followed [these instructions](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation) and tried all 3 available IDE versions (31, 30, 29) but cannot successfully connect to my org's production environment or a developer environment spun off production. I have been able to connect to a new developer sandbox I've just generated to see if that works, so not sure what the issue is.

Steps I've followed are:

1. Install JDK 7 Install Eclipse Kepler 'IDE for Java Developers'
2. In Eclipse installed IDE v31
3. Open Perspective --> Other --> Force.com
4. File --> New --> Force.com project
5. Entered Username, password, security token Selected Production/Developer Edition environment
6. Clicked next
7. At this point I get "Unable to connect to hostname 'www.salesforce.com': Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out."

I'm positive I've got the correct username, pw and token, and I've also tried the above steps with a developer org of the production org (for environment tried both sandbox and Other - test.salesforce.com without success). I've tried all of this with v31, v30 and v29. I've also tried Environment Other - ap1.salesforce.com (the server our SF instance sits on) with the same result.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Chances are you're trying to connect to  salesforce behind your office firewall. You may need to configure proxy setting in eclipse so that you can access salesforce.

Comment: Any result? @Philip Clark ?

Answer (score 1):

Some basic validation it brings to my mind – check if you didn't go through this already!

- See if your account is really locked out
- Is your user account profile has API enabled (hope you might be using System Administrator profile – in case of that this is also enabled by default)
- Try including your IP range in Security Control -> Network Access (it will
  help if IP range was enforced)

Comment: interesting might also be that if your ip is trusted/whitelisted I don't believe you still need the security token.

Comment: I also the same issue.I able to get link with production but no luck at all in sandbox.I am system administrator.my ip range is included and when I check login history no data att all.I wondering what else I should check as I successfully connect to Production but fail in sandbox.

Comment: @unidha Recently there are some certificate related issues, connected with our office admin admin team they installed some certificate and resolved. if you are connecting from office laptop/desktop and using office network check with office IT admin/network team